# Having trouble in getting the number of columns in a table in oracle using TOAD?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

I am trying to get number of columns in a table using the following query:

```
select count(*) 
from user_tab_columns
where table_name='MYTABLE';
```

but the results are shown as zero, even I had many columns in the table.

Could some one help me where I went wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong system table.

Try this.

```
select count(*) from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name='MYTABLE';
```

Comment: Your first statement is not necessarily correct; it depends what schema the table is in. It's equally possible that the table name is incorrect...